# How to simultaneously change a column's type and default value? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, database-migration, migrate

[the "Products" table in schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJt7.png)

In **db/schema** the table **"products"** includes a column name **"quantity"** , its type is string .
Now I want to change its type to integer, and set a default value 1.

I did it by two steps :

*step 1*

`rails g migration change_products_quantity_column_type`

fill in `change_column :products, :quantity, :integer`

then `rake db:migrate`

*step2*

`rails g migration set_default_value_to_quantity`

fill in `change_column_default :products, :quantity, 1`

then `rake db:migrate`

**Can I do this with a single step ? I mean combine the two steps above.**

Comment: Its called column **type** - not attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[change_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column) has the options parameter, so you can do this in one step, like this:

```
change_column :products, :quantity, :integer, default: 1
```